# Why can't I gpg-sign the Ubuntu Code of Conduct?

Tags: launchpad, gnupg, keyrings

So I've spent quite some time trying to sign this code of conduct and am on the verge of abandoning it.

Got right to the sign the txt file stage [https://launchpad.net/codeofconduct/1.1/+sign](http://launchpad.net/codeofconduct/1.1/+sign) but now I get an error and am just tired of fighting with Ubuntu.

It has to do with the clearsign thing in the terminal.

See below

```
$ gpg --clearsign UbuntuCodeofConduct-1.1.txt

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Leon Gert Marincowitz (for launchpad) <lmarincowitz@gmail.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 715FBC94, created 2012-06-16

gpg: can't open `UbuntuCodeofConduct-1.1.txt': No such file or directory
gpg: UbuntuCodeofConduct-1.1.txt: clearsign failed: file open error
```

Comment: Are you sure that the folder permissions are ok? Look at http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html There are the simple example for solve your problem. Have you checked you gpg key, in advance?

Comment: It looks like the code of conduct url is now https://launchpad.net/codeofconduct/2.0/+download

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's do everything in memory to avoid any file permissions, etc. issue:

- `sudo apt-get install xsel` (*xsel* allows terminal programs to copy/paste from the clipboard)
- `wget -O- https://launchpad.net/codeofconduct/1.1/+download | gpg --clearsign | xsel --clipboard`

  - *wget* pipes the Code of Conduct into *gpg*, which pipes the signed output/signature to *xsel*, which pipes it into the clipboard so **you can directly paste it** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on the Launchpad page.
  - This *may* fail the first time because of the wait caused by the graphical GPG passphrase dialog; just do it again and it will go through because the passphrase is cached for a few minutes.

Comment: This is why the Ubuntu community ROCKS!!!!!!!! Thank you Izx thank you!!! It worked, short and sweet!