# How do I add/create a <source.changes> file?

Tags: package-management, ppa, quickly

I have created a package with Quickly and also I have uploaded it to a branch on launchpad, but how can I create a PPA for that program and upload to it? I'm really new to these stuff, I just learned how to use bazaar.

How do I add/create a `<source.changes>` file?

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~/Skriviborð/jebster$ dput ppa:jeggy/jebrowser
Not a .changes file.
Please select a .changes file to upload.
Tried to upload: ppa:jeggy/jebrowser
```

I have added a OpenPGP key if that helps in anyway.

To response to andrewsomething:

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~/Skriviborð/jebster$ quickly share --ppa ppa:jeggy/jebrowser
Get Launchpad Settings
Launchpad connection is ok
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on configuration file `/home/jeggy/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file `/home/jeggy/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on configuration file `/home/jeggy/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file `/home/jeggy/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
User or Team ppa:jeggy not found on Launchpad
ERROR: share command failed
Aborting
```

When I run `debuild -S -sa`, I get this

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~/Skriviborð/jebster$ debuild -S -sa
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S -sa
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
dpkg-buildpackage: source package jebster
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by root <root@jeggy-XPS>
 dpkg-source --before-build jebster
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --with python2,translations
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
running clean
'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/bdist.linux-x86_64' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
  bin/jebsterc
  help/C/figures/icon.png
  help/C/index.page
  help/C/preferences.page
  help/C/topic1.page
  jebster.desktop.in
  po/jebster.pot
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b jebster
dpkg-source: warning: no source format specified in debian/source/format, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: warning: source directory 'jebster' is not <sourcepackage>-<upstreamversion> 'jebster-0.1'
dpkg-source: info: using source format `1.0'
dpkg-source: info: building jebster in jebster_0.1.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building jebster in jebster_0.1.dsc
 dpkg-genchanges -S -sa >../jebster_0.1_source.changes
dpkg-genchanges: including full source code in upload
 dpkg-source --after-build jebster
dpkg-buildpackage: source only upload: Debian-native package
Now running lintian...
E: jebster changes: changed-by-address-malformed root <root@jeggy-XPS>
W: jebster source: diff-contains-bzr-control-dir .bzr
W: jebster source: unused-build-dependency-on-cdbs
W: jebster source: package-needs-versioned-debhelper-build-depends 8
W: jebster source: ancient-standards-version 3.8.3 (current is 3.9.3)
Finished running lintian.
Now signing changes and any dsc files...
 signfile jebster_0.1.dsc root <root@jeggy-XPS>
gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file `/home/jeggy/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file `/home/jeggy/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: skipped "root <root@jeggy-XPS>": secret key not available
gpg: /tmp/debsign.BdtFRCql/jebster_0.1.dsc: clearsign failed: secret key not available
debsign: gpg error occurred!  Aborting....
debuild: fatal error at line 1271:
running debsign failed
```

---

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~/Skriviborð/jebster/debian$ cat changelog
jebster (0.1) precise; urgency=low

  [ Jógvan Olsen ]
  * Initial release.

  [ root ]

 -- root <root@jeggy-XPS>  Mon, 25 Jun 2012 14:53:00 +0100


jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~/Skriviborð/jebster/debian$ gpg --list-keys
gpg: WARNING: unsafe enclosing directory permissions on configuration file `/home/jeggy/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
/home/jeggy/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------------
pub   2048R/1C17B342 2012-03-10
uid                  Ubuntu Accomplishments <jono@ubuntu.com>
sub   2048R/6305AA1F 2012-03-10
sub   2048D/05164E07 2012-03-10

pub   1024R/2868F9C3 2012-06-23
uid                  Jógvan Olsen <jeggy@jebster.net>

pub   2048R/5C24B331 2012-06-24
uid                  Jógvan Olsen <jeggy@jebster.net>
sub   2048R/162F6987 2012-06-24

pub   2048R/2B4F8FE7 2012-06-26
uid                  Jogvan Olsen <jeggy@jebster.net>
sub   2048R/9CF57E08 2012-06-26
```

Comment: Can you `cd` into your source directory, run `debuild -S -sa`, and include the output in your question?

Comment: Thanks! Please post the content of the `debian/changelog` file inside your `jebster` directory; as well as the output of `gpg --list-keys`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, we need to get you ready using the usual PPA process (forget this Quickly business, it seems to be going Slowly ;)

Forgive me for using your full name jeggy, but it's in your Launchpad account so not exactly secret:

1. Sign the Code of Conduct

   - Go to https://launchpad.net/codeofconduct
   - Follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/152049/58612) to sign it in one step.
2. Set your name and modify the changelog, correctly:

   - `E: jebster changes: changed-by-address-malformed root <root@jeggy-XPS>`
   - This is a problem, because your (a) it is in the wrong format, and (b) has no relation to your GPG key.
   - In the terminal, set these variables:

     ```
     export DEBFULLNAME="Jógvan Olsen"
     export DEBEMAIL="jeggy@jebster.net"
     ```
   - Now open the changelog (`debian/changelog`) in *gedit*; carefully select only this signature at the end: 
     `root <root@jeggy-XPS>` and change it to 
     `Jógvan Olsen <jeggy@jebster.net>` making sure spaces before/after are not affected.
   - The final changelog should look something like:

     ```
     jebster (0.1) precise; urgency=low

     \* Initial release.

     -- Jógvan Olsen   Tue, 03 Jul 2012 04:29:33 -0700
     ```
3. Finally, `debuild` and correctly sign the `source.changes`package

   - Run `debuild -S -sa`, and this time you should be asked to sign with your GPG key, `5C24B331`
   - `cd ..`, and then `dput ppa:jeggy/jebster xxxxxxx_source.changes`

Comment: I keep getting this error when trying to sign up for the code of Conduct http://khp.randompoop.net/uploads/Screenshot%20from%202012-07-03%2014:21:37.png

Comment: OK, that's a messy keyring :p. Im not in front of a computer, but if you aren't using the 1024 key, can you delete it with `gpg --delete-secret-key 2868F9C3`, and then try the CoC again -- this time with the `-u "Jógvan Olsen" additional option to gPg if necessary?

Comment: @Jeggy, that error definitely appears to be caused because GPG defaults to the first key, 1024/2868F9C3, and that *does not* have a pub key associated with it. Deleting it as specified in the previous comment should help...

Comment: Yay! Congrats @Jeggy, I look forward to trying `jebrowser` :)    Don't forget the accept/upvote/bounty :D

Comment: i ran into another problem... 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1074824/

Comment: @Jeggy: I'm sorry, that's because of the `-1` in 1.0.0-1 that I used as an example in the changelog; `-N` signifies a Debian revision, so it looks for the original source package. Please see edited answer, the first line/version should be `jebster (0.1) precise; urgency=low`

Answer (score 2):

`.changes` files are PGP signed files that describe the contents of a Debian source package, including Sha256 checksums of the different files and the changelog entry. It is generated when you build a source package, usually done by running `debuild -S`

But you don't need to worry about this! Quickly takes care of all this for you. Just run `quickly share --ppa ppa:jeggy/jebrowser`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work :( i added the output to the question

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem of a setup of launchpad.

I saw your profile page on launchpad.

https://launchpad.net/~jeggy

You can only activate a PPA if you have signed the Ubuntu code of conduct.
Do you activate "Signed  Ubuntu Code of Conduct: yes"?

**How to activate CoC is here:**

[How do I sign the Ubuntu Code of Conduct?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100275/how-do-i-sign-the-ubuntu-code-of-conduct)

If you look already some wrong text and can't post new text, click **Deactivate** button. Please try again from the first.

Then you can see **Signed Ubuntu Code of Conduct: yes** on your profile page of Launchpad, try again the command:

```
quickly share --ppa jeggy/jebrowser
```

I rewrote the answer, in order to arrange a problem.

Comment: wow.. i thought i had done that.... but here's what i get when trying to. `There is 1 error.

(7, 9, u'No public key')`

Comment: When you upload of CoC, did you use an SSH key?
You have to use an OpenPGP key, not an SSH key.

Comment: how do i choose? i have both SSH and PGP key's on launchpad. i just followed the instructions..

Comment: I mistook this for the case of the file which was uploaded simply. In this case, SSH was not related. Please copy & paste the text enciphered by the GPG key.