# How do I upload a .css file to launchpad

Tags: package-management, launchpad

I am trying to upload a `framework.css` file to launchpad with the following command:

```
dput ppa:blade19899/framework.css framework.css_2.0_source.changes
```

but according to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155410/how-do-i-add-create-a-source-changes-file) `source.changes` file is a file generated by `debuild -S`.

**My question is**: *How do I upload a non debian file(a `.css` file) to launchpad?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload individual files such as that to Launchpad PPAs.

You must create a `deb` source package to upload to a PPA. If all you have is a single CSS file, you probably don't want to package it and manage a PPA. You can instead use the `Create a release` link on the page for your project, and add it as a download file there.

Comment: i Tried `bzr push lp:~blade19899/+junk/framework.css framework.css` and `bzr push lp:~blade19899/+junk/framework.css` but both times i get an error?

Comment: You can't push a single file to somewhere that doesn't exist. You must create a branch, add the file to the branch, commit the file, then push the branch to Launchpad.

Comment: @blade19899 I am looking to upload a single text file without going through the debian/source process.  Did you have to create a Project on LaunchPad, or did you end up pushing/uploaded your file (from your computer with say a local instance of a bzr repository) to you personal PPA via the 'junk' URL?

Comment: @Bernmeister sorry, I completely forgot about this Q, I don't think I ever finished this. Reading the answer from dobey should help you a bit.

Answer (score -1):

You can upload individual files to launchpad if you are using bzr and you run a commit without building a package.  @Dobey is mostly right though.  It's abnormal to do this for non-Canonical employed humans.