# How to install gcc 4.9 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, gcc, g++

[Now that gcc 4.9 is officially released](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2014-04/msg00195.html), is there an easy and convenient way to install it on Ubuntu 14.04 through the package manager (ie. apt-get)?

I would also appreciate information on how to properly configure my system to use it as its compiler.

Comment: I was hoping for a more convenient answer now that the release is official.

Comment: That is, the process in that link seems error-prone.

Comment: No, there isn't. Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software to know why

Comment: That's a shame. I was hoping for some kind of quick and convenient way to upgrade to the experimental version. Do you think I should leave this question open, or should I accept mohtaw's answer?

Answer (score 0):

it's the same issue in the following link

[Getting + installing gcc/g++ 4.9 on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428198/getting-installing-gcc-g-4-9-on-ubuntu)

it says ,

download all these:
`binutils_2.24-3_amd64.deb
cpp-4.9_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
g++-4.9_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
gcc-4.9_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
gcc-4.9-base_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libasan1_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libatomic1_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libcilkrts5_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libgcc1_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libgcc-4.9-dev_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libgomp1_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libitm1_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
liblsan0_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libmpfr4_3.1.2-1_amd64.deb
libquadmath0_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libstdc++-4.9-dev_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libstdc++6_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libtsan0_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libubsan0_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb
libvtv0_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb`

From Debian's servers, e.g.:

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.9/libgcc-4.9-dev_4.9-20140218-1_amd64.deb

Then install them, e.g.: $ for package in *.deb; do sudo dpkg --install "$package"; done